# Cannot get to trigger onActivityResult() android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a `DataActivity` which has to ask the user to fill out a form and then return the data to `MainActivity`

`DataActivity` is called from `MainActivity` like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, DataActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_OK);
```

`DataActivity` should return data intent to `MainActivity` like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("funcX", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.data_eq_x)).getText().toString());
i.putExtra("funcY", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.data_eq_y)).getText().toString());
i.putExtra("constants", (Serializable)constants);
setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
finish();
```

but `onActivityResult` is never called in `MainActivity` after this...
Whenever i try to access `funcX` or `funcY` in `MainActivity`, I get NullPointerexception.

NOTE: `constants` variable can be and in fact was null when i was testing this code.

I'm developing on Android 2.2 on the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation for the parameter [requestCode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) on [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

> requestCode   If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult()
>   when the activity exits.

RESULT_OK is equal to -1..

Change your request code to some positive value for it to work

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DataActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i,345);
```